# How to access multiple list boxes from view to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

i am developing one website where i want to assign my orders to delivery boys so i am using multiple list boxes as given below with the code.

[image]

code of this screen is given below.

```
<?php
                                            $CurrentOrders = FoodyComments::where('comment_date', '<=', new DateTime('today'))
                                                    ->select('comment_ID', 'comment_post_ID', 'comment_date')
                                                    ->get();

                                            $CurrentOrdersCount = FoodyComments::where('comment_date', '<=', new DateTime('today'))
                                                            ->get()->count();
                                            foreach ($CurrentOrders as $CurrentOrders) {
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{$CurrentOrders->comment_ID}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{$CurrentOrders->comment_post_ID}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{$CurrentOrders->comment_date}}
                                                    </td>

                                                    <?php
                                                    $Count = DeliveryStaffDetails::get()->count();
                                                    $c = 1;
                                                    $current_orders_count = 1;
                                                    ?>

                                                    <td><select name="$current_orders_count">
                                                            <?php while ($c != $Count + 1) { ?>
                                                                <option id ="<?php echo $c; ?>"  value="<?php echo $c; ?>"><?php echo $c; ?></option>
                                                                <?php $c++;
                                                            }
                                                            ?>
                                                        </select>

                                                    </td>

                                                    <?php $current_orders_count;
                                                }
                                                ?>
```

Here i am giving dynamic names to  so that i will get different names for each list box.

Below is my Controller code to access this list boxes.

```
public function postOrders() 
{
    $CurrentOrdersCount = FoodyComments::where('comment_date', '<=', new DateTime('today'))->get()->count();

    $x=1;
    while($x!=$CurrentOrdersCount+1) {
        $mylist = $_POST[$x];
        echo $mylist;
    }
}
```

But it is not working. What is wrong over here?

Comment: What is not working exactly ?

Comment: Just an observation, a lot of the logic in your view should really be in your controller.

Comment: You don't need `$_POST[$x];`. You can use `Input::get()`. Laravel-like.